# Transferring javascript variables from client to server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am programming a strange script that consists of transferring variables from client to a nodejs server.
So if a have a date variable, how can I transfer it and use the same variable on the server?
Is there any way to serialize objects and retrieve them on server side in a way that they remain the same type (date, function, variable, string, object...)?


Thank you

Comment: Just don't use `eval()`, whatever you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check out DNode in addition to nowjs. I've been watching both of those projects but not dabbled in them yet. However, I get the sense that DNode it is building more traction in the node.js community and I hear praise for it all the time.

https://github.com/substack/dnode
http://substack.net/posts/85e1bd/DNode-Asynchronous-Remote-Method-Invocation-for-Node-js-and-the-Browser

Timezones are very important in my application, so I've found that serializing dates to  ISO8601 formatted strings for dates works best. @Mike's solution is great if you don't care about timezones, or can assume that all dates are UTC. There are plenty of javascript libraries to help serialize/deserialize ISO8601.

Comment: It appears that the now.js project was abandoned several months ago. http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4667826

Comment: Is it possible to synchronize variables between the client and the server using dnode?

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize a date by converting it to a number which can be sent via JSON.

```
new Date(+new Date)
```

is perfectly valid.

The prefix `+` in

```
+new Date
```

converts the newly created date to a number, and

```
new Date(myNumber)
```

reconstitutes a date from a number.

Answer (score 1):

Now.js could abstract all of the serialisation, deserialisation.. it provides a shared namespace between node.js server and browser client:

http://nowjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

As was posted before me, serialize the `Date Object` to a string literal, either the value in miliseconds or the formatted `Date` String.

Use a POST request passing the `Date` string in the request body or a GET requests passing the string via query parameter to get it to the server. There you may deserialize the string using the `Date` constructor.